# Realtek RLT8812AU can't start monitor mode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb

I have this problem with Kali Linux on VirtualBox. I have a USB network card:

```
root@kali:~# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
```

I tried all week to install many drivers, but I still get the same error:

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       rtl8812au   Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU
802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter cat: /sys/class/ieee80211/phy0/device/net/wlan0mon/type: No such file or directory

Newly created monitor mode interface wlan0mon is *NOT* in monitor
mode. Removing non-monitor wlan0mon interface...

WARNING: unable to start monitor mode, please run "airmon-ng check kill"
```

I tried `airmon-ng check kill`. Not working. Any ideas how to find good drivers?

Comment: Btw, most of the opensource realtek drivers in the kernel are crap. Some of them work, some of them not, but all of them is crap. I am s*ing with an rtl8172u (from belkin), it works only in security-less Managed mode. Generally with wifi cards, particularly with usb-based or realtek ones, often the chipset simply doesn't allow the monitor or master modes. If it allows, then often the driver doesn't allow. Why the heck they couldn't solve it with full OS-side control, nobody on the world can say it.................... well really I could, but it would be moderated out...

Comment: Does your device support monitor mode in the first place? Check with `iw phy0 info`.

Comment: Supported interface modes: * IBSS * managed * AP * monitor * P2P-client  * P2P-GO

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Are you using the driver provided by realtek? what is the driver version ( install `lshw` then run `lshw -class network | grep driverversion`)?

Comment: My driver version: `configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.2.15 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s`

Comment: The wifi driver isn't listed , try to install the  `RTL8812AU` from git repo , the official driver dosn't support the monitor mode , (e,g: https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)

Comment: @GAD3R I tried that version but it doesn't support it. I tried https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux too but no luck there either.
Output for both are the same
`autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s`

Comment: once I connect to a network it does show up in `airmon-ng`: `wlx00c0ca96172e  Unknown  rtl8812au - [phy6]` and it does open a monitor but `airodump-ng` doesn't show any channels

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it.
Use: `https://github.com/kimocoder/rtl8812au`

```
git clone git@github.com:kimocoder/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
git checkout v5.1.5
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Now ignore `airmon-ng` and set the monitor yourself.

(In my case wlx00c0ca96172e is your average wlan1)

```
ip link set wlx00c0ca96172e down
iw dev wlx00c0ca96172e set type monitor
ip link set wlx00c0ca96172e up
```

Now `airodump-ng wlx00c0ca96172e` works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have Kali as a VirtualBox VM and I installed the AWUS036ACH driver with

```
apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
```

After that, run the following commands to activate the monitor mode:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```